# How to integrate Highcharts in a symfony 3 project?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts, symfony

I am trying to integrate OBHighChartsBundle in my symfony project. I followed the tutorial at 
https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle
this is my code :

In the controller:

```
 /**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @Route("/admin")
 * @Route("/admin", name="home_admin")
 */
public function adminAction(Request $r)
{
    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('piechart');
    $ob->title->text('Browser market shares at a specific website in 2010');
    $ob->plotOptions->pie(array(
        'allowPointSelect'  => true,
        'cursor'    => 'pointer',
        'dataLabels'    => array('enabled' => false),
        'showInLegend'  => true
    ));
    $data = array(
        array('Firefox', 45.0),
        array('IE', 26.8),
        array('Chrome', 12.8),
        array('Safari', 8.5),
        array('Opera', 6.2),
        array('Others', 0.7),
    );
    $ob->series(array(array('type' => 'pie','name' => 'Browser share','data' => $data)));


    return $this->render("@Tahwissa/Admin/index.html.twig", array(
        'chart' => $ob
    ));
}
```

in My view index.html.twig:

```
<!-- Load jQuery from Google's CDN if needed -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/Js/highcharts.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/Js/exporting.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    {{ chart(chart) }}
</script>

<div id="linechart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I have a blank page and an exception occured :

Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
Highcharts Error #13

Rendering div not found

This error occurs if the chart.renderTo option is misconfigured so that Highcharts is unable to find the HTML element to render the chart in.

Comment: renderto `piechart` in js and `linechart` in div